# ArrayList objects - How do the constructors work, and what is their time complexity?

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm trying to gather information on how the constructors in the ArrayList class work and what their time complexity is for a class project.

In the API documentation at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#ArrayList(),

it states that get(), set() isEmpty(), iterator(), and listIterator() are the only O(1) methods.

I'm taking this to mean that the constructors are O(n), but I can't seem to find anything out there specifically stating this, nor how the constructors function.

Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why not take a look at the code? http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/ArrayList.java

Comment: Awesome, thanks for this great resource.  This shows me exactly what I need.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ArrayList(int)` will basically just allocate an array of size n, and nothing else.  That's probably technically O(n), but the complexity of allocation is...itself fairly complex, and frequently just O(1) albeit with overhead in the garbage collector later...

`ArrayList(Collection)` will basically just call `toArray()` on the target collection and use that, which will take...however long it takes for that collection type, which is essentially always O(n).